# COPY Last row from WB1 and paste in last row WB2

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbook 1. thisWB 2. newWB
Now i need to copy data from lastblank row + 1 of thisWB to newWB workbook and paste in lastblank row + 1.
I have put some codes like below but it do not work, could you suggest what is the problem with the below code

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim blankcell As Long
blankcell = Columns(1).Find("", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Windows(thisWB).Sheets("BS All Entities").Rows(blankcell + 1 & ":" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=Windows(newWB).Sheets("BS All Entities").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Thank you for all your help in advance.
KR
Manoj

Comment: `lastblank row + 1`? Did you mean data from the last used row?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rngLastColumnOld As Long
Dim rngLastRowOld As Long
Dim rngTemp As Range
Dim rngFirstBlankOld As Range
Dim rngCopyFrom As Range
Dim rngFirstBlankNew As Range


With Windows(thisWB).Sheets("BS All Entities")
    Set rngTemp = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If rngTemp Is Nothing Then
                rngLastColumnOld = 1
            Else
                rngLastColumnOld = rngTemp.Column
            End If
    rngLastRowOld = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set rngFirstBlankOld = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
    Set rngCopyFrom = .Range(rngFirstBlankOld, .Cells(rngLastRowOld, rngLastColumnOld))
End With

Set rngFirstBlankNew = Windows(newWB).Sheets("BS All Entities").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow

rngFirstBlankNew.Resize(rngCopyFrom.Rows.Count, rngCopyFrom.Columns.Count).Value = rngCopyFrom.Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Hi

sorry i was not so clear, here is what i want

I have two Workbook 
1. Father.xlsx
2. Mother.xlsx

in Workbook one (Father.xlsx) after some 100 rows there is a blank row and below to it some data again.I want to copy these rows to workbook two (Mother.xlsx) where already some data is present, i want to paste these copied rows to workbook two after leaving a blank row.

So in short a programme which can identify last row on workbook one copy all the data below that then go to workbook two find the last ending row and then leave one row blank and paste the data.

Comment: You want to copy the some 100 rows before the blank row is found? Or everything below the blank row? If you want everything below the blank row, will that be all the data to the bottom of the sheet?

Comment: everything once it encounter a blank row, i mean anything, even blank

Answer (score 0):

Go thru this link

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/755467-using-visual-basic-applications-paste-data-multiple-sheets.html

only change is instead of same workbook sheets i am using different workbook sheets